# Identification of average treatment effect in Pearl's introductory article

Tags: causality

I'm trying to understand the identification of the average treatment effect in [Pearl's introductory paper on causal inference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2836213/).

We have the following structural equation model:
\begin{align}
z &= f_Z(u_Z) \\
x &= f_X(z, u_X) \\
y &= f_Y(x, u_Y)
\end{align}
where the exogenous variables $U_Z, U_X, U_Y$ are assumed mutually independent. Regarding the average effect of $X$ on $Y$, Pearl shows that $E(Y | do(x_0)) = E(Y | X = x_0)$ by deriving expressions for each of these quantities individually.

1. First, Pearl states that $E(Y | do(x_0)) = E(f_Y(x_0, u_Y))$. **How can I arrive at this expression?** I can see that
   \begin{align}
   E(Y | do(x_0)) &= \sum_y y P(y | do(x_0)) \\
   &= \sum_{y, z} f_Y(x_0, u_Y) P(y, z | do(x_0)),
   \end{align}
   but how do I eventually equate this to $\sum_{x, y, z} f_Y(x_0, u_Y) P(x, y, z)$?
2. Second, Pearl shows that
   \begin{align}
   E(Y | X = x_0) &= E(f_Y(X, u_Y) | X = x_0) \\
   &= E(f_Y(x_0, u_Y) | X = x_0) \\
   &= E(f_Y(x_0, u_Y)).
   \end{align}
   I understand the second equality on an intuitive level, I guess. **How can I justify the last equality?**

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is there a particular line or substitution in the final equality that you find confusing?

Comment: No, I guess that the last equality is OK if $U_Y$ is assumed to be independent of $X$. I'm struggling more with the first part of the question about the causal quantity $E(Y | do(x_0))$.

Comment: You write "But how do I eventually equate this to ...". In the expression that follows, $x$ appears to be the values taken by $X$, but doesn't the do operator set $X=x_0$?

Comment: Yes, $x$ represents the values taken by $X$. Indeed, the do-operator sets $X = x_0$, but the expression you're referring to is the expectation wrt the observational distribution $P$, which is the joint distribution of $(X, Y, Z)$. Recall that I'm trying to understand why the interventional expectation $E(Y | do(x_0)) = \sum_y y P(y | do(x_0))$ equals the observational expectation $E(f_Y(x_0, u_Y)) = \sum_{x, y, z} f_Y(x_0, u_Y) P(x, y, z)$.